# Jenkins 2.14 - Cannot create new job -> empty page

Tags: jenkins-2

I've done a fresh installation of Jenkins 2.14 on Debian (apt-get install jenkins). Installation is correct, proxy is well configured.
But when I try to create new Job (New item), I've got an empty page.
I'm an administrator with all rights so I guess it is not a problem with rigths management.

There is no errors in logs even if I set the log level to all.

Any clues will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT : I try with firefox and Chrome. Same result.

EDIT2 : I try with 2.13, 2.10, 2.3 without success. When I came back to 1.656 the new Job widows is displayed normally.

Jean-Marc

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when I upgraded from 1.5 to 2.66 . After a little research I got my issue resolved. what I did is just upgraded the plug in external monitor job plug in to latest version 1.7 as of now.

References : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36875

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36875

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Environment+Plugin